# VisualStateManager not working in Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm currently working on a Windows Universal App and I defined a `UserControl` called `IconButton`

*IconButton.xaml*

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Common">
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation To="Red" Storyboard.TargetName="path" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

<Grid>
    <Path x:Name="path" Data="{x:Bind IconPathData, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="White" />
</Grid>
```

*IconButton.xaml.cs*

```
public sealed partial class IconButton : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconPathDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IconPathData", typeof(string), typeof(IconButton), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string IconPathData
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(IconPathDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconPathDataProperty, value); }
    }

    public IconButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, MouseOver.Name, true);
    }
}
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate.aspx) the `GoToState` method expects `VisualState` with the given name passed to the method. In my case there is a `VisualState` with `x:Name="MouseOver"` so `GoToState` should be able to find this.
Unfortunately `GoToState` always returns false which should only happen if it cannot find a `VisualState` with a given name.
I really don't know what to do to solve this. The documentation is quite straight forward and several examples from the web do it the same way as I do but they get it working.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Try `PointerOver` instead of `MouseOver`

Comment: `MouseOver` is just the name of the `VisualState` and should be irrelevant to `GoToState` as long as I provide the right name (see the MSDN link). As expected if I replace `MouseOver` with `PointerOver` nothing changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't show the full content of `IconButton.xaml`, I assume it looks somewhat like:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App1.IconButton"
    ...
    PointerEntered="UserControl_PointerEntered">

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        ...
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid>
        <Path ... />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If so, move the `VisualStateManager` inside the `Grid` (intead of being a direkt child of `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App1.IconButton"
    ...
    PointerEntered="UserControl_PointerEntered">

    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Common">
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation To="Red" Storyboard.TargetName="path" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Path x:Name="path" ... />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```